# EF Core 2.0 Tools strange behavior

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.0

I'm using EF Core 2.0 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 package for it. I have migration A and B applied to the database and I want migration B to rollback and delete completely from the project.
To rollback migration B I execute this command in Package Manager Console

```
 Update-Database -Migration A
```

In the result of this command the B migration is rolled back. Which is good.
But when I execute

```
Remove-Migration
```

I receive this error

```
   The migration 'B' has already been applied to the database. Revert it and try again. If the migration has been applied to other databases, consider reverting its changes using a new migration.
```

Which is strange, because I've just rolled it back explicitly with update database command.

It appeared that when I executed remove migration command this actually triggered Startup.Configure() method and within this method I do my

```
dbContext.Seed();
```

and within my Seed method I have

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

which is why my rolled back migration was applied again.

So, my question is why EF Core 2.0 Tools trigger Startup.Configure() method, because this did not happen for EF Core 1.1 ?

Comment: Take a look at [Upgrading applications from previous versions to EF Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/1x-2x-upgrade) topic of the documentation, especially the **New way of getting application services** part under **Breaking Changes**.

Comment: I looked at this upgrading instructions, but it does not answer my question

Comment: The point was to try the new way with `public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)`. May be if they don't find it, they invoke `Startup.Configure`, who knows. Or could simply be one of the many EF related bugs. I don't think someone will answer *why*, but good luck.